# Watermarking an image

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a small bit of code and I wonder if I can make it more readable. I would appreciate it if some people could take a look at it and give me some feedback. I especially wonder if there is a beter way of doing this:

```
cv::Mat image = loadImage(path.string());
if (image.data == NULL) { continue; }
```

This is the bigger code:

```
cv::Mat Watermarker::loadImage(const std::string& path)
{
    if (!validFile(path))
    {
        if (!std::filesystem::is_directory(path))
        {
            std::cout << path << " is invalid\n";
        }

        return cv::Mat{};
    }

    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(path, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    if (image.data == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Not enough permissions to read file " << path << "\n";
        return cv::Mat{};
    }

    return image;
}

void Watermarker::mark(const std::string& targetDirectory, const std::string& watermarkPath)
{
    cv::Mat watermarkImage = loadImage(watermarkPath);
    if (watermarkImage.data == NULL) { return; }

    // Loop through all the files in the target directory
    for (const std::filesystem::path& path : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(targetDirectory))
    {
        cv::Mat image = loadImage(path.string());
        if (image.data == NULL) { continue; }

        cv::resize(watermarkImage, watermarkImage, image.size());

        // Give the images 4 channels
        cv::cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
        cv::cvtColor(watermarkImage, watermarkImage, cv::COLOR_RGB2RGBA);

        // Add the watermark to the original image
        cv::addWeighted(watermarkImage, 0.3, image, 1, 0.0, image);

        saveImage(targetDirectory + "/watermarked_images/" + path.filename().string(), image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: You loop through stuff and You skip some, that is perfectly readable. I am pretty sure You are mistaken to think Your code is not readable.

Comment: (Some think this question should not be answered *as is* for *lack of review context*. Given the spotlight "on the conditional continue", there is enough context for *that*. For `::loadImage()` and `::mark()`, documenting comments should work miracles. Please heed [What (not) to do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).)

Answer (score 3):

## Don't ignore errors

You are just skipping any file that cannot be read correctly. But probably, if the user tried to process the images in a given target directory, it wants all of them to be watermarked, and if something cannot be watermarked, the user probably wants to hear about it. So you should not just continue after loading an image failed, you should stop and report an error. There are several ways to do this, for example:

## Consider throwing exceptions

I would recommend throwing exceptions here. I assume that not being able to open a file or parsing it correctly is an exceptional event for your program. The advantage of throwing an exception is that the caller of a function that throws doesn't have to handle the exception, it can just let it propagate up the stack until something does handle it, or if nothing handles the exception, the program will abort with an error. The latter can even be desirable. Here is an example of how to throw exceptions:

```
#include <stdexcept>

cv::Mat Watermarker::loadImage(const std::string& path)
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(path, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    if (!image.data)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to read image");

    return image;
}
```

I have removed the check for `path` being valid as well, since if it isn't valid, trying to call `cv::imread()` on it will fail as well.

Inside `Watermarker::mark()`, you can now assume that when `loadImage()` returns, `image.data` is always non-NULL, so you don't need a check there. If you really want to continue parsing images, then you can catch the exception, and perhaps print a warning so the user does get to know what was wrong:

```
try {
    cv::Mat image = loadImage(path.string());
    cv.resize(...);
    ...
} catch (std::runtime_error &e) {
    std::cerr << "Could not load " << path << ": " << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

## Write error messages to `std::cerr`

Don't write warnings, errors and debug messages to `std::cout`, but use `std::cerr`. This is especially important if the program is printing normal output to `std::cout`, so that if standard output is redirect to a file for example, it will not contain error messages, and the error messages will still be printed to the console.

## Avoid converting `std::filesystem::path`s to `std::string`s too early

Use `std::filesystem::path` as the type to pass paths in consistently. Only convert them to/from `std::string`s when really necessary. You can also make use of implicit conversions between `std::string` and `std::filesystem::path`. So for example:

```
cv::Mat Watermarker::loadImage(const std::filesystem::path& path)
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(path, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    ...
}
```

And:

```
void Watermarker::mark(const std::fileystem::path& targetDirectory, const std::filesystem::path& watermarkPath)
{
    auto watermarkImage = loadImage(watermarkPath);

    for (auth& path : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(targetDirectory))
    {
        auto image = loadImage(path);
        cv::resize(watermarkImage, watermarkImage, image.size());
        ...
        saveImage(targetDirectory / "watermarked_images" / path.filename(), image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aborting the process (throwing) on error seems not great tho, that'd leave the target directory half processed and as you don't want to water mark files twice, recovering from that is annoying. I think printing an error is better, this is what most UNIX tools do too

Comment: @EmilyL. When a thrown exception is not caught, the program aborts with a diagnostic printed to standard error output (at least, on UNIX-like operating systems), and a non-zero exit code. As for not watermarking twice unnecessarily, that is useful even if there are no errors, and should be implemented by checking if a watermark image is already present and has a timestamp that is newer than the source.

Comment: The convention with tools like cp, mv, convert etc is to keep going and print the (hopefully few) files that failed. Each to their own tho.

Comment: @EmilyL. cp and mv continuing even if some things fail is sometimes helpful, sometimes not. But I agree that it's better to follow the conventions of other commonly used programs so that there is the least amount of surprise.